# Apache2 Virtual Host Confusion

Tags: web, apache2, debian

I'm trying to setup my website so that it has proper subdomains.

For example, if a person goes to portfolio.beaudoinapps.com, I want them to see my portfolio page.

Here is my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.portfolio.beaudoinapps.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/portfolio
    ServerAdmin jonathan@beaudoinapps.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/websites/portfolio-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/websites/portfolio-access_log common
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.temp.beaudoinapps.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/temp
    ServerAdmin jonathan@beaudoinapps.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/websites/temp-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/websites/temp-access_log common
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/home
    ServerAdmin jonathan@beaudoinapps.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/websites/home-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/websites/home-access_log common
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

What I need help with is how do I make it so if the subdomain doesn't exist(in this case if the portfolio is not temp.beaudoinapps or portfolio.beaudoinapps) it redirects user to www.beaudoinapps.com

Also, can the way I redirect http traffic to https proper? Thanks!